# change the visibility of silverlight control's parent node, the silverlight control got reloaded

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to hide a silverlight control in html. The problem is if the code of hiding is called by silverlight control, after the we make it visible again, the silverlight got reloaded, all the data in silverlight control would be lost.

the following is a simple sample which can show you the problem.
silverlight control:
    mainpage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Button Content="Hide" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,210,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <sdk:Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,92,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="323" />
</Grid>
```

MainPge.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Browser;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    [ScriptableMember()]
    public event EventHandler TestEvent;

    public string timeStr;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.label1.Content = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Control", this);

        timeStr = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestEvent(sender, new TestEventArgs());
    }

    [ScriptableMember]
    public string GetTime()
    {
        return timeStr;
    }
}

public class TestEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    [ScriptableMember()]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TestEventArgs() {
        this.Name = "Test";
    }
}
}
```

Test.html

```
  function show() {
document.getElementById("silverlightControlHost").style.visibility = "visible";
//document.getElementById("silverlightControlHost").style.display = "";
}

    function hide() {
        document.getElementById("silverlightControlHost").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
        //document.getElementById("silverlightControlHost").style.display = "none";
    }

    function showTime() {
        var timeStr = app.Content.Control.GetTime();
        document.getElementById("timeDiv").innerHTML = timeStr;
    }

    var app;
    function silverlightOnLoad() {
        alert("load");
        app = document.getElementById("silverlightApp");
        app.Content.Control.TestEvent = function (sender, arg) {
            //if you keep these two alert statement. while the first one works fine,     //you can see the second one would
            //throw an error after the silverlight control is hidden.
            // alert(arg.Name);
            hide(); 
            //alert(arg.Name);
        };
    }

 <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show" onclick="show();" />
<input type="button" id="btnHide" value="Hide" onclick="hide();" />
<input type="button" id="Button1" value="Show Time" onclick="showTime();" />
<div id="timeDiv">

</div>
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object id="silverlightApp" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap" />
        <param name="onLoad" value="silverlightOnLoad" />
        <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration: none">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                style="border-style: none" />
        </a>
    </object>
    <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
        border: 0px"></iframe>
</div>
```

if hide the silverlight control by the "hide" button from html, all works fine. but when hide the control by the button from silverlight control, the silverlightOnLoad would be called again when you click "show" button. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks similar to http://forums.silverlight.net/p/17061/57793.aspx.

In short words: Silverlight plug-in exits when the plug-in is focused and you try to hide it. Try to call `window.focus();` (or set focus to any other focusable element on HTML page) before hiding the plug-in:

```
app.Content.Control.TestEvent = function (sender, arg) {
  window.focus();
  hide(); 
};
```